# Trying to implement a LINQ to HLSL provider. Are there any good HLSL tutorials? Specifically ones that focus on the syntax

Tags: linq, syntax, hlsl

Are there any good tutorials for HLSL specifically ones that gives a good explanation on the syntax? I am dumbfounded when presented with samples that show register(s0) and ones that show tex0, are these always the same? The MSDN documentation reads like a manual and isn't easy to follow.

I am an absolute beginner on HLSL and I am trying to implement a custom LINQ provider for HLSL ([details](http://drviking.wordpress.com/2010/12/20/presenting-linqtoshader/)) and so far, its working, but I am sure that it will fail on most cases.

My Linq provider is supposed to translate a LINQ query into HLSL and compile it. Given this query (this shader creates an HDR image out of three images):

```
 Texture texSampler1 = GraphicsContext.Textures[0];
 Texture texSampler2 = GraphicsContext.Textures[1];
 Texture texSampler3 = GraphicsContext.Textures[2];
 float threshold = 0.33f;
 var shader = from input in GraphicsContext.Pixel
              let pos = input.GetMember<float2>("pos")
              let color1 = HlslMethods.tex2D(texSampler1, pos)
              let color2 = HlslMethods.tex2D(texSampler2, pos)
              let color3 = HlslMethods.tex2D(texSampler3, pos)
              let avg1 = (color1.r + color1.g + color1.b) / 3
              let avg2 = (color2.r + color2.g + color2.b) / 3
              let avg3 = (color3.r + color3.g + color3.b) / 3
              let thresholdMultiplicand = (1 / (HlslMethods.max(1 - threshold, threshold)))
              let diff1 = Math.Abs(avg1 - threshold) * thresholdMultiplicand
              let diff2 = Math.Abs(avg2 - threshold) * thresholdMultiplicand
              let diff3 = Math.Abs(avg3 - threshold) * thresholdMultiplicand
              select new
              {
                  Color = ( color1 * (1f - diff1 + diff2 + diff3) + 
                            color2 * (1f - diff1 - diff2 + diff3) + 
                            color3 * (1f + diff1 + diff2 - diff3)) / 3
              };
```

should result into this HLSL shader:

```
sampler2D texSampler1 : register(s0);
sampler2D texSampler2 : register(s1);
sampler2D texSampler3 : register(s2);

struct MyPixelShader2Input
{
    float2 pos : TEXCOORD0;
};

float4 MyPixelShader2(MyPixelShader2Input input) : COLOR
{
    float2 pos = input.pos;
    float4 color1 = tex2D(texSampler1, pos);
    float4 color2 = tex2D(texSampler2, pos);
    float4 color3 = tex2D(texSampler3, pos);
    float avg1 = (((color1.r + color1.g) + color1.b) / 3);
    float avg2 = (((color2.r + color2.g) + color2.b) / 3);
    float avg3 = (((color3.r + color3.g) + color3.b) / 3);
    float thresholdMultiplicand = (1 / max((1 - 0.33), 0.33));
    float diff1 = (abs((avg1 - 0.33)) * thresholdMultiplicand);
    float diff2 = (abs((avg2 - 0.33)) * thresholdMultiplicand);
    float diff3 = (abs((avg3 - 0.33)) * thresholdMultiplicand);
    float4 output = ((((color1 * (((1 - diff1) + diff2) + diff3)) + (color2 * (((1 - diff1) - diff2) + diff3))) + (color3 * (((1 + diff1) + diff2) - diff3))) / 3);
    return output;
}
```

What I am having trouble now is with semantics mostly, especially value-semantics (I haven't found many examples using them). Real world examples would also be really helpful. I'm not sure what kind of shaders are used out there.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, I am a total novice with shaders myself. But the Shazzam Shader Editor is totally invaluable when messing about with HLSL code, it's simply magic.

Comment: Which shader model are you targeting?

Comment: I just tried shazzam and it is awesome. I'm trying to target the latest shader model so that would be SM 4.1.

Answer (score 0):

From DXSDK:

Type Register Description:

- b: Constant buffer
- t: Texture and texture buffer
- c: Buffer offset
- s: Sampler
- u: Unordered Access View

This is for SM 5.0. If you are only targeting SM 4.0 or less, you don't have UAVs. For SM 3.0 or less there's no clean separation between samplers and textures. My advice is to always use sampler register syntax (`register(s0)` is the same than `tex0`).